# Compare Array and remove object

Tags: javascript

I have this code below i'm trying to remove the entire row `{"id": "Apple", "group": 1}` by comparing the `graph` with the `testArray` to see for each object that the `graph` have in common with the `testArray` just remove the entire row. But i'm not really sure on how to complete remove it any help would be greatly appreciated

```
var graph = {   "nodes": [
    {"id": "Apple", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cherry", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tomato", "group": 3}
    ],
    "links": [
    {"source": "Apple", "target": "Cherry", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cherry", "target": "Tomato", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Tomato", "target": "Apple", "value": 1}
    ]
    };

    var testArray = ['Apple'];

    var nodes = graph["nodes"];
    let removeNodes = nodes;
    removeNodes.forEach((obj) => {
        if (testArray.includes(obj.id.toString())) 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping the testArray and find each item in the nodes array and remove it?

Edit: If you want to remove by given key, you can make a function that accepts the object key and the list.

```js
var graph = {
  nodes: [
    {
      id: "Apple",
      group: 3
    },
    {
      id: "Cherry",
      group: 3
    },
    {
      id: "Tomato",
      group: 3
    },
    {
      id: "Lemon",
      group: 4
    },
    {
      id: "Grape",
      group: 5
    }
  ],
  links: [
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Cherry",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      source: "Cherry",
      target: "Tomato",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      source: "Tomato",
      target: "Apple",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      source: "Lemon",
      target: "Grape",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      source: "Grape",
      target: "Lemon",
      value: 1
    }
  ]
};

function removeObject(key, arr) {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    // get all nodes that has the value of item
    const foundNodes = graph.nodes.filter(node => arr.includes(node[key]));
    // get index of each found item
    foundNodes.forEach((node) => {
      const nodeIndex = graph.nodes.indexOf(node);
      // remove item by index
      graph.nodes.splice(nodeIndex, 1);
    })
  });
}


// find object by group
removeObject('group', [3]);
console.log(graph);
```

Comment: Thanks that works great but may i ask if i want to do it another way and not by comparing the `testArray` for example i want to remove it based on the group number  so like if 'group:1' remove it

Comment: Sorry but it only removes one of the object may i ask if you can check my code here is my JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tbj82hef/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `graph["nodes"]` and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on `testArray` and mutate graph object.

```js
var graph = {   "nodes": [
    {"id": "Apple", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cherry", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tomato", "group": 3}
    ],
    "links": [
    {"source": "Apple", "target": "Cherry", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cherry", "target": "Tomato", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Tomato", "target": "Apple", "value": 1}
    ]
    };

let testArray = ['Apple'];

graph["nodes"] = graph["nodes"].filter(x => !testArray.includes(x.id));

console.log(graph);
```

**Ad-hoc request from comments:**

To remove element if group = 1

```
graph["nodes"] = graph["nodes"].filter(x=> x.group !== 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Using the index, we can remove the element using splice().

I've used slice to make a copy of the nodes array.

```js
var graph = {
      "nodes": [
        { "id": "Apple", "group": 1 },
        { "id": "Cherry", "group": 2 },
        { "id": "Tomato", "group": 3 }
      ],
      "links": [
        { "source": "Apple", "target": "Cherry", "value": 1 },
        { "source": "Cherry", "target": "Tomato", "value": 1 },
        { "source": "Tomato", "target": "Apple", "value": 1 }
      ]
    };
    
    var testArray = ['Apple'];
    
    // var nodes = graph["nodes"];
    let removeNodes = graph["nodes"].slice();
    removeNodes.forEach((obj, index) => {
      if (testArray.includes(obj.id)) {   //Why toString()? obj.id is already a string.
        graph.nodes.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
```

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/kokumipixi/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

My take on this using the filter approach. No more if conditions

```js
var graph = {   "nodes": [
        {"id": "Apple", "group": 1},
        {"id": "Cherry", "group": 2},
        {"id": "Tomato", "group": 3}
        ],
        "links": [
        {"source": "Apple", "target": "Cherry", "value": 1},
        {"source": "Cherry", "target": "Tomato", "value": 1},
        {"source": "Tomato", "target": "Apple", "value": 1}
        ]
        };
    
        var testArray = ['Apple'];
    
        var nodes = graph["nodes"];
        let removeNodes =   nodes.filter((node)=>{
        return testArray.includes(node.id);
      });
      console.log(removeNodes);
```

Simple is the best! 
Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zsr0ugfq/3/

Okay to avoid confusion here. this will show the removed Items. 
Just put a ! in the return and it will suit the OP's need.
I think sometimes it's okay to show how things can be solve.

Comment: Why are you returning the removed object? Did you understand the OPs post?

Comment: I understand it, but decided to show how the incuded in testArray can be remove. Just put ! in the return and it will be suffice the OP's need.